# Salvamento simultâneo de entidades relacionadas

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp-net-core

Boa tarde. Estou com uma dificuldade que eu creio que seja algo bem simples mas como sou novo na área estou enfrentando um problema absurdo. Tenho 2 entidades (a nível de exemplo), uma chamada AERONAVE e a outra chamada AERONAVE_DOCUMENTO, que possuem relacionamento de um para muitos (1 aeronave tem vários documentos e 1 documento apenas uma aeronave). Pois bem:

SEGUE AS ENTIDADES:

```
public class Aeronave : Entity
{
    protected Aeronave()
    {
    }

    public Aeronave(string matricula, string fabricante, string categoria, string modelo)
    {
        Matricula = matricula;
        Fabricante = fabricante;
        Categoria = categoria;
        Modelo = modelo;
    }

    public string Matricula { get; set; }                       // OBRIGATÓRIO (5)
    public string Fabricante { get; set; }                      // OBRIGATÓRIO (50)
    public string Categoria { get; set; }                       // OBRIGATÓRIO (20)
    public string Modelo { get; set; }                          // OBRIGATÓRIO (30)
    
    // RELATIONSHIP
    public IEnumerable<AeronaveDocumento> AeronavesDocumentos { get; set; }
}

public class AeronaveDocumento : Entity
{
    protected AeronaveDocumento()
    {
    }

    public AeronaveDocumento(string titulo, DateTime? dataEmissao, DateTime dataValidade, string arquivo, Guid aeronaveId)
    {
        Titulo = titulo;
        DataEmissao = dataEmissao;
        DataValidade = dataValidade;
        Arquivo = arquivo;
        AeronaveId = aeronaveId;
    }

    public string Titulo { get; set; } // OBRIGATÓRIO (1,50)
    public DateTime? DataEmissao { get; set; } // OPCIONAL
    public DateTime DataValidade { get; set; } // OBRIGATÓRIO
    public string Arquivo { get; set; } // OPCIONAL

    // RELATIONSHIPS
    public Aeronave Aeronave { get; set; }
    public Guid AeronaveId { get; set; } // OBRIGATÓRIO
}
```

O problema é o seguinte: No meu front, no formulário de criação de AERONAVE eu criei um formarray para que a pessoa pudesse já adicionar quais documentos ele quiser dessa aeronave. Pois bem, no back está chegando lá na controller a entidade aeronave junto com a lista, PORÉM, na hora que eu chamo o repositório da aeronave para salvar, ele salva apenas a aeronave e desconsidera os documentos, ele não está fazendo o salvamento dos documentos já direto. Sei que é erro meu e possivelmente uma besteira, mas não sei como resolver.

SEGUE A CONTROLLER DE AERONAVE (METODO INSERT):

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] AeronaveEditViewModel model) // nessa model ele está recebendo a coleção de documentos, mas não os salva. Assim como na entidade, nessa viewmodel também está presente a coleção de AeronaveDocumentoViewModel
    {
        var aeronave = new Aeronave(model.Matricula, model.Fabricante, model.Categoria, model.Modelo);
        _aeronaveService.Insert(aeronave, true);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Você recebe os documentos via POST e faz o que com eles? ali onde você instancia uma nova Aeronave no construtor, não da a entender que você atribui também os documentos.